# iOS - How to verify files that my app created are encrypted

Tags: ios, encryption, entitlements, data-protection, ios-enterprise

In my app I've enabled "Data Protection" in XCode -> Capabilities (Also in the developer.apple.com). I've set the "Sharing and Permission" to be "Complete Protection" in developer.apple.com. Everything looks correct in the setup. The app runs fine. But how do I know that the files are actually encrypted? I tried to see the files in a text viewer (Xcode -> Window -> Device and Simulators -> ... -> Download Container) but the files appears to be in clear text, not encrypted.

Comment: You might try accessing the file with an app such as iExplorer. Accessing in the simulator is likely to have different results since the encryption implementations are different.

Comment: I'm using a real device - data protection is not enabled on simulators. and iExplorer seems to not work anymore. I have macOS High Sierra and iExplore seem not to work on it.

Comment: Just tried iExplorer ver 4.1.15 and macOS 10.13.4. I can see files and directories in apps.